# How to avoid mvn cobertura plugin affecting xpath return type in apache camel route

Tags: apache-camel, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

I am using apache camel 2.12.0 (tried also 2.14.0). 
I have a route where I receive xml from remote server:

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<response><meta><code>200</code></meta><data><person><name>John</name></person></data></response>`

```
from("direct:start")
.to("jetty:http://localhost/something")
.transform().xpath("/response/data")
.log("${body.class}")
.unmarshal().xstream();
```

I cut out body of  unmarshal it. using xstream.

`.log("${body.class}") -> net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMNodeList`

Until now all works fine. mvn test, mvn camel:run.. all fine.

**Now the error part**

`mvn cobertura:cobertura` throws exception

`org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: [net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyElementImpl@90400f] of type: java.util.ArrayList on: Message: [net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyElementImpl@90400f]`

`.log("${body.class}") -> java.util.ArrayList`

**Help**

Can you please give an advice why cobertura changes return type of xpath()?

**UPDATE** (solved)

I found the problem with dependencies. 
If I use camel-xstream and cobertura, I get weird behavior in .xpath(). 
But if I include also camel-xmljson lib in the dependencies,then all works fine. 
I suppose the one of the coberturas dependency to jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1-beta-8:compile or some other one loads xml classes which collide with camel.

Comment: Maybe you can exclude some maven dependencies in the cobertura plugin which it adds to the classpath, maybe its adding saxon or some other xml libraries you can exclude.

Comment: I wonder, will an explicit `.convertBodyTo(DesiredType.class)` help?

Comment: .convertBodyTo() didn't help
but thanks to idea of Claus Ibsen, tried to find conflicts in the dependencies and found the cause. See update of the question